# wp query should be reset by wp_reset_query(); by this function or not

Tags: php, wordpress

I used the following code in my wordpress site many time in single page

```php
<?php $recent = new WP_Query("showposts=4&cat=186");
      while ($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"target="_blank"><b><li>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    </b></li>
</a><br>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Now my question is, what should I reset it by `wp_reset_query();` or not if your answer is yes then how ?

Answer (score 1):

try this code below end your loop end use WordPress function

```
<php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `showpost` argument is replaced by `posts_per_page`.

You need to reset the `global $post` after each custom loop if you need to access to the original `$post`'s values (like get_the_ID(), etc ...).

The line `wp_reset_query();` need to be after `endwhile`.

PS: You need to reset the query because you use `$the_post->the_post()`.

Comment: dear thank you for your response and what should i define function in function.php or use without define

Comment: You have nothing to do in `functions.php`. Just add the `wp_reset_query()` after your loop.